# Matplotlib "ValueError: x and y must be the same size"

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a scatter plot very similar to [image: this].

My code is below. I'm comparing two groups of schools, one in a system and the other group is that system's peers. 
This was modeled after the directions found [here](https://chrisalbon.com/python/matplotlib_simple_scatterplot.html).

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
plt.scatter(sys_peers_sat_earning['MD_EARN_WNE_P6'][sys_peers_sat_earning['SystemorPeer'] == 'USM'],
            sys_peers_sat_earning['SAT_AVG'][sys_peers_sat_earning['SystemorPeer'] == 'USM'],
            marker='x',
            color='b',
            alpha=0.7,
            s = 124,
            label='USM Schools')
plt.scatter(sys_peers_sat_earning['MD_EARN_WNE_P6'][sys_peers_sat_earning['SystemorPeer'] == 'Peer'],
            sys_peers_sat_earning['SAT_AVG'][sys_peers_sat_earning['SystemorPeer'] == 'Peer'],
            marker='x',
            color='b',
            alpha=0.7,
            d = 124,
            label='USM Peers')
plt.title('SATs and Earnings of Students Not Enrolled 6 Yrs. After Entry')
plt.ylabel('Median earnings of students working and not enrolled 6 years after entry')
plt.xlabel('Average SAT equivalent score of students admitted')
X_train[:,0]
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
```

errors both with and without the line of `X_train[:,0]` mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41659535/valueerror-x-and-y-must-be-the-same-size) came as follows: `ValueError: x and y must be the same size`

Can someone talk to me like I'm two with steps on how to edit this?

Comment: Your chances of getting help will be much higher, when providing a [mcve] of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that

```
sys_peers_sat_earning['MD_EARN_WNE_P6'][sys_peers_sat_earning['SystemorPeer'] == 'USM']
```

(your x value)

has a different size than

```
sys_peers_sat_earning['SAT_AVG'][sys_peers_sat_earning['SystemorPeer'] == 'USM']
```

(your y value)

Confirm this by renaming them into x and y respectively and check their length:

```
len(x) == len(y)
```

this will tell you if x and y are indeed the same size.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I did run this and it stated it was true
`len(sys_peers_sat_earning['MD_EARN_WNE_P6']) == len(sys_peers_sat_earning['SAT_AVG'])`

Comment: I tried to even make a very simple scatter plot from this and got the same error `plt.scatter(sys_peers_sat_earning.MD_EARN_WNE_P6, sys_peers_sat_earning.SAT_AVG)`

Comment: I ran the test outlined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37784165/matplotlib-scatter-array-lengths-are-not-same) with this `print(sys_peers_sat_earning['MD_EARN_WNE_P6'].shape)
print(sys_peers_sat_earning['SAT_AVG'].shape)`

and got this `(143,)
(143, 2)`
Is this of any help to you?
(143, 2)

Comment: When looking for the `size` you cannot compare `len`! While both arrays obviously have the same length (143) in this case, they do not have the same size. One is 1-dimensional, the other 2-dimensional. This means you are asking matplotlib to plot a 1D array against a 2D array, which fails.

Comment: Ok thank you but do you have some insight on how to fix the code?

Comment: The two of you helped me identify the problem and i thank you for that but can someone direct me on how to fix the code? I still have no idea and am getting pretty anxious about this. :-(